# What regex parser is used for the files_pattern for the 'COPY INTO' sql query?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

(Submitted on behalf of a Snowflake User)

---

I have a test s3 folder called s3://bucket/path/test=integration_test_sanity/file.parquet

I want to be able to load this into snowflake using the COPY INTO command but I want to be able to load all the test folders which have a structure like test=*/file.parquet.

I've tried:

```
COPY INTO raw.test_sanity_test_parquet
                        FROM 's3://bucket/path/'
                        CREDENTIALS=(AWS_KEY_ID='XXX' AWS_SECRET_KEY='XXX')
                        PATTERN='test=(.*)/.*'
                        FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = parquet)
```

and also

```
COPY INTO raw.test_sanity_test_parquet
                        FROM 's3://bucket/path/'
                        CREDENTIALS=(AWS_KEY_ID='XXX' AWS_SECRET_KEY='XXX')
                        PATTERN='test=.*/.*'
                        FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = parquet)
```

Neither of these works. I was wondering what regex parser is used by Snowflake and which regex I should use to get this to work.

This works but I can't filter on just test folders which can cause issues

```
COPY INTO raw.test_sanity_test_parquet
                        FROM 's3://bucket/path/'
                        CREDENTIALS=(AWS_KEY_ID='XXX' AWS_SECRET_KEY='XXX')
                        PATTERN='.*/.*'
                        FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = parquet)
```

---

Any recommendations? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
COPY INTO raw.test_sanity_test_parquet
            FROM 's3://bucket/path/'
            CREDENTIALS=(AWS_KEY_ID='XXX' AWS_SECRET_KEY='XXX')
            PATTERN='.*/test.*[.]parquet'
            FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = parquet)
```

Comment: Hey Abhi, Is this possible when you are reading data from Azure Data lake Store Gen 2 as well? because I am not able to do this. Please guide.

Comment: Well thanks alot, great answer. Now I am able to use it.